# What are the known standards to map country names to super regions APAC, EMEA, and AMER?

Tags: standards

I am looking for country-superregion mapping for the following super regions:

- APAC = Asia Pacific
- EMEA = Europe, Middle-East and Africa
- AMER = North, Central and South America

So far I have only seen a compiled list [on GitHub as a gist](https://gist.github.com/richjenks/15b75f1960bc3321e295). Would be great to have a standard list and wonder where I may be able to find such information.

Comment: Have you tried Wikipedia?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_groupings

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Vincé Yes I have. It has listing at a continent/region level (e.g., Asia, Middle East), but I am hoping to find something similar to GeoNames that is a standardized set of tables.

Comment: @PolyGeo Ah good idea. Let me also post the question there. Thank you!